# Custom icon font not working with XeTeX/fontspec

Tags: fonts, fontspec

I made a custom icon font using [Fontself maker](https://www.fontself.com), that contains only few icons in the slots of latin characters. For this MWE I made a font *Duck Face* ([download form my server](https://kunden.tobiw.de/DuckFace.otf)) containg only a space char and the letter `D` which is a duck*.

```
% !TeX program = xelatex
\documentclass{scrartcl}

\usepackage{fontspec}
\newfontfamily\iconfont{Duck Face}

\begin{document}
\Huge
D
\par
\iconfont
D
\par
\end{document}
```

However the compilation fails with

```
Error 11 (driver return code) generating output;
file bfs-test.pdf may not be valid.
SyncTeX written on bfs-test.synctex.gz.
Transcript written on bfs-test.log.
```

But without further (understandable) error messages in the LOG. What is wrong with the the custom font? Or is XeTeX only capable of loading fonts containing a certain range of characters?

---

<sup>* The duck is taken from https://openclipart.org/detail/170850/cartoon-duck</sup>

Comment: I also asked for help on Twitter: https://twitter.com/tobiasweh/status/1014929579335733250

Comment: Interesting! For me, it compiles without error but the PDF is empty (ie I am not able to open the file). 
I opened your font with FontForge and generated a TrueType font. Using this, everything works fine. So, I guess, there is something wrong with your font file. XeLaTeX is definitely fine with any range of characters. I already used my own icon fonts without any problems.

Comment: if I use `xelatex --no-pdf ` it runs without error but xdvipdfmx on the resulting xdv file produces no output and reports `[1]Segmentation fault (core dumped)` which isn't good....

Answer (score 7, accepted):

FontForge’s `fontlint` reports:

```
A point in D is outside the font bounding box data.
ERROR      2 Self-intersecting glyph
ERROR      5 Missing points at extrema
ERROR     34 Bad 'CFF ' table
ERROR     80 Missing BlueValues entry in PostScript Private dictionary
FAIL         DuckFace.otf
```

Fortunately, FontForge can fix as well as report many errors.  I’ve often fixed fonts by simply clicking `File` and `Generate Fonts`, thereby making a (repaired) copy under a different name. In this case, FontForge suggests the name `DuckFaceRegular.otf`, and the newly generated font works with both xetex and luatex:

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\newfontface\iconfont{DuckFaceRegular.otf}
\begin{document}
\Huge
D

\iconfont
D
\end{document}
```

[image: output]

Curiously, `fontlint` reports most of the same errors and some new ones in the newly generated font, but for reasons I don’t understand, they’re no longer fatal for compilation of a `.tex` file:

```
The advance width of space (290) does not match the font's advanceWidthMax (579) and this is a fixed pitch font
A point in D is outside the font bounding box data.
The advance width of uni00A0 (290) does not match the font's advanceWidthMax (579) and this is a fixed pitch font
ERROR      2 Self-intersecting glyph
ERROR      5 Missing points at extrema
ERROR     34 Bad 'CFF ' table
FAIL         DuckFaceRegular.otf
```

Comment: Thanks this solved the issue. I contacted the developers of the Illustrator Extension I used to create the fonts, maybe it is a bug in their software or they can tell me what I did wrong … (see link to the Tweet in the comment below my question to stay tuned)

Answer (score 4):

```
xelatex --no-pdf file
```

runs without problems but when use

```
xdvipdfmx -vvv
```

to convert the resulting xdv file you get a segmentation fault and a log as below which gives several warnings about things wrong in the font file before it gives up:

```
<FONTMAP:/usr/local/texlive/2018/texmf-var/fonts/map/pdftex/updmap/pdftex.map><FONTMAP:/usr/local/texlive/2018/texmf-var/fonts/map/dvipdfmx/updmap/kanjix.map><FONTMAP:/usr/local/texlive/2018/texmf-dist/fonts/map/dvipdfmx/ckx.map>aa739 -> aa739.pdf
DVI File Info
Unit: 25400000 / 473628672
Magnification: 1000
Media Height: 42967693
Media Width: 28548252
Stack Depth: 5
Page count:     1
DVI Comment:  XeTeX output 2018.07.05:1902

DVI file font info
TeX Font: ./DuckFace.otf loaded at ID=   29, size=24.79pt (scaled 248.8%)
TeX Font: /usr/local/texlive/2018/texmf-dist/fonts/opentype/public/lm/lmroman17-regular.otf loaded at ID=   28, size=24.79pt (scaled 248.8%)
TeX Font: /usr/local/texlive/2018/texmf-dist/fonts/opentype/public/lm/lmroman10-regular.otf loaded at ID=   14, size=10.91pt (scaled 109.5%)
<AGL:texglyphlist.txt><AGL:pdfglyphlist.txt><AGL:glyphlist.txt>[1</usr/local/texlive/2018/texmf-dist/fonts/opentype/public/lm/lmroman17-regular.otf@24.79pt<NATIVE-FONTMAP:/usr/local/texlive/2018/texmf-dist/fonts/opentype/public/lm/lmroman17-regular.otf/0/H/65536/0/0>
fontmap: /usr/local/texlive/2018/texmf-dist/fonts/opentype/public/lm/lmroman17-regular.otf/0/H/65536/0/0 -> /usr/local/texlive/2018/texmf-dist/fonts/opentype/public/lm/lmroman17-regular.otf(Identity-H)

pdf_font>> Input encoding "Identity-H" requires at least 2 bytes.
pdf_font>> The -m <00> option will be assumed for "/usr/local/texlive/2018/texmf-dist/fonts/opentype/public/lm/lmroman17-regular.otf".
(CID:LMRoman17-Regular)
pdf_font>> Type0 font "/usr/local/texlive/2018/texmf-dist/fonts/opentype/public/lm/lmroman17-regular.otf" cmap_id=<Identity-H,0> opened at font_id=</usr/local/texlive/2018/texmf-dist/fonts/opentype/public/lm/lmroman17-regular.otf/0/H/65536/0/0,0>.
><./DuckFace.otf@24.79pt<NATIVE-FONTMAP:./DuckFace.otf/0/H/65536/0/0>
fontmap: ./DuckFace.otf/0/H/65536/0/0 -> ./DuckFace.otf(Identity-H)

pdf_font>> Input encoding "Identity-H" requires at least 2 bytes.
pdf_font>> The -m <00> option will be assumed for "./DuckFace.otf".
(CID:DuckFaceRegular)
pdf_font>> Type0 font "./DuckFace.otf" cmap_id=<Identity-H,0> opened at font_id=<./DuckFace.otf/0/H/65536/0/0,1>.
></usr/local/texlive/2018/texmf-dist/fonts/opentype/public/lm/lmroman10-regular.otf@10.91pt<NATIVE-FONTMAP:/usr/local/texlive/2018/texmf-dist/fonts/opentype/public/lm/lmroman10-regular.otf/0/H/65536/0/0>
fontmap: /usr/local/texlive/2018/texmf-dist/fonts/opentype/public/lm/lmroman10-regular.otf/0/H/65536/0/0 -> /usr/local/texlive/2018/texmf-dist/fonts/opentype/public/lm/lmroman10-regular.otf(Identity-H)

pdf_font>> Input encoding "Identity-H" requires at least 2 bytes.
pdf_font>> The -m <00> option will be assumed for "/usr/local/texlive/2018/texmf-dist/fonts/opentype/public/lm/lmroman10-regular.otf".
(CID:LMRoman10-Regular)
pdf_font>> Type0 font "/usr/local/texlive/2018/texmf-dist/fonts/opentype/public/lm/lmroman10-regular.otf" cmap_id=<Identity-H,0> opened at font_id=</usr/local/texlive/2018/texmf-dist/fonts/opentype/public/lm/lmroman10-regular.otf/0/H/65536/0/0,2>.
>]
otf_cmap>> Creating ToUnicode CMap for "/usr/local/texlive/2018/texmf-dist/fonts/opentype/public/lm/lmroman17-regular.otf"...

otf_cmap>> Creating ToUnicode CMap for "./DuckFace.otf"...

otf_cmap>> Creating ToUnicode CMap for "/usr/local/texlive/2018/texmf-dist/fonts/opentype/public/lm/lmroman10-regular.otf"...
(CID:/usr/local/texlive/2018/texmf-dist/fonts/opentype/public/lm/lmroman17-regular.otf[NRPACS+LMRoman17-Regular][CIDFontType0][2 glyphs][578 bytes])(CID:./DuckFace.otf[ARUFOD+DuckFaceRegular][CIDFontType0]
```